# How can I split concatenated strings that contain no delimiters in python?

Tags: python, string, split, delimiter

Let's say I have a list of concatenated firstname + lastname combinations like this:

```
["samsmith","sallyfrank","jamesandrews"]
```

I also have lists `possible_firstnames` and `possible_lastnames`.

If I want to split those full name strings based on values that appear in `possible_firstnames` and `possible_lastnames`, what is the best way of doing so?

My initial strategy was to compare characters between full name strings and each `possible_firstnames`/`possible_lastnames` value  one by one, where I would split the full name string on discovery of a match. However, I realize that I would encounter a problem if, for example, "Sal" was included as a possible first name (my code would try to turn "sallyfrank" into "Sal Lyfrank" etc).

My next step would be to crosscheck what remains in the string after "sal" to values in  `possible_lastnames` before finalizing the split, but this is starting to approach the convoluted and so I am left wondering if there is perhaps a much simpler option that I have been overlooking from the very beginning?

The language that I am working in is Python.

Comment: A possible strategy is to create all possible combinations of (first_name, last_name) from candidate lists and then compare joint string with the one in your original list. Of course, the number of elements in candidate lists may be restricting factor in this case, but for reasonably short lists it will work.

Answer (score 4):

If you are getting similar names, like sam, samantha and saman, put them in reverse order so that the shortest is last

```
full_names = ["samsmith","sallyfrank","jamesandrews", "samanthasang", "samantorres"]
first_name = ["sally","james", "samantha", "saman", "sam"]

matches = []

for name in full_names:
    for first in first_name:
        if name.startswith(first):
            matches.append(f'{first} {name[len(first):]}')
            break

print(*matches, sep='\n')
```

Result

```
sam smith
sally frank
james andrews
samantha sang
saman torres
```

This won't pick out a name like *Sam Antony*.  It would show this as *Saman Tony", in which case, your last name idea would work.

It also won't pick out *Sam Anthanei*.  This could be Samantha Nei, Saman Thanei or Sam Anthanei if all three surnames were in your surname list.

Comment: Thanks for your response! The issue that you discuss at the end does pose a problem for me. This FN/LN scenario is actually just something that I made up to be roughly comparable to the real task I face (I'm splitting Japanese reading values for Chinese character compound words: `{"行動":"koudou"}` → `{"行動":["kou","dou"]}` etc.), where the sort of issues you describe are likely enough to occur. It's reassuring to know that I am not overlooking any kind of simple solution though, so thank you for verifying this! I will continue trialing ways to mitigate the discussed issues :)

Comment: It really depends on whether you are reading Japanese or Chinese.  In Chinese, it is one word one sound - a lot easier to split.  In Japanese, it is one word many sounds.  eg 光山 in Chinese is guang shan but in Japanese, it is hikari yama.  Chinese has beginnings and endings which are paired together to make a sound.   In this case gu and sh, which can't form words by themselves and ang and an which can form words by themselves.  Japanese is completely different.  If it is surnames, Chinese surnames are normally a single character.  Japanese surnames normally tend to be 2 characters.

Answer (score 1):

##### Is this what u wanted

```py
names = ["samsmith","sallyfrank","jamesandrews"]
pos_fname = ["sally","james"]
pos_lname = ["smith","frank"]

matches = []

for i in names:
    for n in pos_fname:
        if i.startswith(n):
            break
    else:
        continue
    
    for n in pos_lname:
        if i.endswith(n):
            matches.append(f"{i[:-len(n)].upper()} {n.upper()}")
            break
    else:
        continue

print(matches)
```